# Adding admin-ajax.php to the frontend. Good or bad idea?

Tags: themes, ajax

I love admin-ajax.php. But I hate having to localize in order to point frontend scripts to it, and I wish there was an equivalent, easy-to-find file for themes. (It also just bothers me to see frontend requests go through "/wp-admin/". No practical reason, just looks ugly IMO.)

So I've simply copied admin-ajax.php to the root dir at "/ajax.php", adjusted the include paths and removed the WP_ADMIN constant definition. Seems to work like gangbusters (I can now just direct all my frontend AJAX requests to /ajax.php! And I can still use the normal wp_ajax hooks in my plugins!).

But is this safe? What might go wrong? Since this isn't built into core, I assume there's a good reason as to why not. But looking through the code, I can't see any immediate problems.

You're smart--tell me if this approach is crazy. Or if there's a simpler method that I'm overlooking.

Comment: You might forget about and miss this file during automatic updates, which could result in things breaking and leaving security vulnerabilities in place.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could just use a RewriteRule to your .htaccess above the regular permalink rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^ajax$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [L]
```

Now send your AJAX requests to `example.com/ajax`, and never miss core changes to that file after upgrades.

Comment: Great idea! It's one of those things that, after you hear it, you think "that's so simple and obvious!" Thanks.

Comment: I added the rewrite rule as per your suggestion but `example.com/ajax` URL 404's. Could you elaborate on where exactly within the `.htaccess` should I add this. I have it currently between `# BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule> # END WordPress`

Comment: This works. I was missing the trailing slash. I have permalinks set to /%postname%/

Answer (score 8):

**First:** standardization. If you plan on using community plugins, chances are they are not going to care about your `/ajax.php` file in the document root. So they won't use it.

If you're going to roll everything yourself, this isn't an issue.

**Second:** what if the core updates? Will you monitor and change your ajax file?

**Third**: despite `admin-ajax.php` residing in `wp-admin`, it does not load any of the admin area stuff (eg. list tables, etc). Nor does it check auth or expose anything sensitive to non-logged in users. It's just like a front-end file, in other words. Nothing to worry about.

**Fourth:** Related to the first issue, some plugins will check before blindly loading ajax related functionality.  An example is below. Your modified ajax.php will likely not cause that to load.

```
<?php
if (is_admin() && defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) {
    //  load ajax stuff
}
```

**Finally:** What you complain about, using the localization to get the Ajax URL is a good thing to do. Why? Because Your JS files are not aware of any of the server side stuff. You're going to hard a URL in that will break if/when the site moves? Seems like a bad choice.

If you really don't want to localize every script that uses Ajax, simple hook into `wp_head` really early and spit out the admin ajax URL. Problem solved (this is exactly how the admin area does it, by the way).

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse83650_lazy_ajax', 0, 0);
function wpse83650_lazy_ajax()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var ajax_url = "<?php echo esc_js(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>";
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! All valid points. The biggest thing you helped me realize is that, though I wasn't thinking of this as a "core hack" (since I was adding, not modifying a file), it really is since it depends on other functionality in core that may change. Not *too much* different from any other plugin (which may also die after changes in core functionality), but definitely philosophically different. Thanks for the thoughts!

Comment: Re: "_Third: ... Nothing to worry about._", what about when trying to lock-down the wp-admin directory eg using .htaccess rules to limit to known-safe IP ranges?  I presume some kind of exception would need to be made for the ajax-admin.php file? (I say "presume" because I'm a numpty when it comes to .htaccess rules, and don't really know if this is possible?).

Comment: It should be possible to allow a single file, yes.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy this is a brilliant answer, thank you. I am trying to have admin-ajax loaded on the front end as I am reverse proxying the siteurl to my staging/home url. Please look at this: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253041/ajax-load-more-and-masonry-is-it-possible-to-load-admin-ajax-php-in-the-front-e) Is it possible to do it with 3rd party plugin? Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Regarding point 3: https://10up.github.io/Engineering-Best-Practices/php/#ajax-endpoints ; "WordPress provides an API to register AJAX endpoints on wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. However, WordPress does not cache queries within the administration panel for obvious reasons. Therefore, if you send requests to an admin-ajax.php endpoint, you are bootstrapping WordPress and running un-cached queries. Used properly, this is totally fine. However, this can take down a website if used on the frontend."

Answer (score 5):

As with many things in WordPress, there are a near infinite number of ways to skin the cat.  While all of the accepted methods work, I have found that they are less "neat" than using [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to include ajax capability on the front end.

Check this out:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se83650_js' );
function se83650_js()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'se83650-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/se83650.js',  'jquery', '1.0.0', true );
    // First param is the name of the script you are attaching it to - in this case
    // it is the name of the custom script we added.  Second param is the name of 
    // the javscript Object that will be attached with your information.
    // Third param is an array of attributes, in this case, ajaxurl
    wp_localize_script( 'se83650-js', 'se83650Ajax', 
        array(
            // You can put any variables here you want for your script
            // such as plugin-specific variables or nonces, etc.
            'ajaxurl'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}
```

And then in the `se83650.js` file, you would reference your variable with `se83650Ajax.ajaxurl`.

The benefit of this technique is that if you end up with many plugins that try and duplicate this functionality, they aren't including or overwriting the same variable.  `ajaxurl` is pretty generic to include, this gets you more contained and it plays nicer with other developers.