# How to rewrite AJAX call URL to admin-ajax.php to match REST style URLs

Tags: url-rewriting

Let's say I have an AJAX callback setup using admin-ajax.php that fetches WordPress posts when query parameters are passed in the URL. A typical URL for an AJAX call using the GET method would look like:

`http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/?action=get_posts&user_id=1`

Now I would like to rewrite this to something like:

`http://example.com/rest/posts/1`

I'm able to rewrite URL for pages using WordPress native `generate_rewrite_rules` hook. But that doesn't work for admin-ajax.php as Wordress hasn't even loaded when admin-ajax.php is called. Any ideas on how to get this setup?

Comment: Have you seen and tried [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83652/73) or [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91195/73)?

Comment: I did try earlier, the htaccess hack that you suggested in the answer that you linked. Though it serves the purpose of rewriting the AJAX url to a different location, I'm not sure how it could be modified to map "multiple" query parameters. Like in example above `posts` should refer to `action=get_posts` and `1` should refer to `user_id=1`. And if I have an additional query parameter, let's say `page` then that should also map correctly.

Comment: Inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` like in the second link.

Comment: I took a look at the second link but could not find anything relevant to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The method `get_api_values()` does it: `strtok( $request, '/' );` separates the values from each other.

Comment: So you mean to say the rewrite URL pattern in htaccess would remain the same, i.e. `RewriteRule ^rest/$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [L]` for all URLs and I must extract the value inside of the admin-ajax.php?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the most flexible approach, because you don’t have to change the .htaccess each time you extend your parser.

Comment: Great! Thx. This has given me the base to start.