# Using AJAX to generate front end / viewer end pages

Tags: plugins, wp-query, ajax

I am currently trying to send certain data via POST method from code in the widget of my plugin to the theme's archive.php page.

The code that contains the data for jquery/ajax is :

```
<a class="ajax-post" data-year="'.$previous ->year .'" data-month="'.$previous->month.'" data-category="'.$category.'" href="' . filter_date_link($category,$previous->year, $previous->month, $day=false) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($previous->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $previous->month, 1, $previous->year)))) . '" id="previous_link">&laquo; ' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($previous->month)) . '</a></td>';

$calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next"><a class="ajax-post" data-year="'.$next ->year .'" data-month="'.$next->month.'" data-category="'.$category.'"href="' . filter_date_link($category,$next->year, $next->month, $day=false) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($next->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $next->month, 1, $next->year))) ) . '" id="next_link">' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($next->month)) . ' &raquo;</a></td>';
```

The js code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $('#next_link').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var $aid =$('#next_link'),
         year =$aid.data('year'),
         month =$aid.data('month'),
         category =$aid.data('category');

     });

    $('#previous_link').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var $aid =$('#previous_link'),
         year =$aid.data('year'),
         month =$aid.data('month'),
         category =$aid.data('category');

     });

    console.log('category: ' + category);

    $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         timeout: 8000,
         type: 'POST',
         data: {year : year, month: month, category: category},
         url: '/path/myfile.php',
         success: function(data) {},
         error: function() {}
    });

});
```

And the page where this code will be used is:

```
<?php
//Specific class for post listing */
$blog_type = sq_option('blog_type','masonry');
$template_classes = $blog_type . '-listing';
if ($blog_type == 'standard' && sq_option('blog_meta_status', 1) == 1) { $template_classes .= ' with-meta'; }

add_filter('kleo_main_template_classes', create_function('$cls','$cls .=" posts-listing '.$template_classes.'"; return $cls;'));

if(isset($_POST['category'])){

        $category=$_POST['category'];

        $year=$_POST['year'];

        $month=$_POST['month'];

        if(isset($_POST['day'])) {

            $args = array('category_name' => $category , 
            'date_query' => array(             
                                  array(
                                    'year' => $year,                     
                                    'month' => $month,                                           
                                    'day' => $day,
                                    ),                                                               
                                    'column' => 'post_date',                          

                                ),
            );
```

The `$args` array will be used to create a new query in the WP Loop.

I am fairly experienced with php yet AJAX and jQuery are a bit new to me.

What am I missing what do I need to add/ take away to make it work.

**UPDATES:**

- when using the code above and checking console in the debugger I get:
  *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*
- fixed the above issue by using the solution suggested by the kaiser, however I now get this mistake, on line 29 of my jQuery : *Uncaught ReferenceError: category is not defined* .
- Question that for now I failed to find a comprehensible answer to : ' Where do I include the localisation and call to jQuery so that the variables are actually passed in post format?

Here is the code where I use enqueue to attach the script in my plugins file ( not sure if the right place or the right way ):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );

function theme_enqueue_scripts() {

  // Enqueue and Localize AJAX JavaScript Functions File 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-categories-js', plugins_url( 'events-calendar-manager/inc/js/js.js' ), array('jquery'));

}
```

Comment: In the tag archive of [tag:ajax] you will find some starting points on how WP runs AJAX. Further more you are using closures attached to the `click` events. This means that the scope of the variables is _inside_ the functions and does not bleed outside. Your result therefore always will be an `undefined` variable in your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are pointing to a non existing AJAX file.

```
$.ajax( {
     // ...
     url : '/path/myfile.php',
     // ...
} );
```

WordPress has a predefined file for that:

```
admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
```

When you are running *public* queries, then you need to add it to

```
wp_localize_script( 'your-script-handle', 'yourJavaScriptAccessibleObject', array(
    'ajaxurl' => esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ),
) );
```

If you are just running admin facing calls, then you can even leave that out and simply use

```
ajaxurl
```

in your JavaScript file as the variable is prefilled. In case you have a single setup, you can use [this hack for Apaches `.htaccess` file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83652/385).

Keep in mind that you want to secure your AJAX calls by using a NONCE:

```
'_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'your-script-handle' ),
```

Comment: sry kaiser I still can't give you vote up  :( my rep is 2 low

Comment: @dev3078 you can select it as solution by ticking the checkmark below the voting arrows.