# Ajax Load More and Masonry: is it possible to load admin-ajax.php in the front end?

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am using the plugin [Ajax Load More - Infinite Scroll](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) together with [Masonry grid](http://masonry.desandro.com/). For example, my index.php includes the following:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(‘[ajax_load_more post_type=”post” category=”‘ . $wp_query->query_vars[‘category_name’] . ‘” tag=”‘ . $wp_query->query_vars[‘tag’] . ‘” offset=”8″ posts_per_page=”10″ pause=”true” scroll=”false” button_label=”Show me more posts.” transition_container=”false” transition=”none”]’); ?>
```

All seems to work fine, but when moved the blog behind a reverse-proxy on the staging area, I have issues with calling the admin-ajax.php from wp-admin (either 403 or very long loading time for the ALM articles) as it is not allowed through the reverse proxy rules in Apache. From the source page, I can see, in fact, the following:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var alm_localize = {“ajaxurl”:”http:\/\/siteurl\/test\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php”,”alm_nonce”:”0dge8w13b3″,”pluginurl”:”http:\/\/homeurl\/test\/wp-content\/plugins\/ajax-load-more”,”scrolltop”:”false”};
/* ]]> */
```

where the ajaxurl is still where my WP core installation files reside, while the pluginurl is correctly my homeurl (that accessible to the users).

I have the following question:

- Can you bypass the loading of admin-ajax.php directly from wp-admin and rather making it load on the front page? I have found references of use of `wp_enqueue_script()` and from:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

However, I am not sure how this can be used with the Ajax Load More - Infinite Scroll plugin and. Can you help?

- Is it secure to include an Apache rule to give access to that particular script?

Thank you for your help,

N.

**EDIT1:**

So, I have come up with this:

```
//localize the admin-ajax.php
 $localiser = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ),
  );
  wp_localize_script( "ajax-load-more", "alm_localize", $localiser );

  //Define plugin constant
  define( 'AJAX_PLUGIN', dirname( __FILE__ ) );

  //Register script
  wp_register_script( 'ajax-load-more', 'AJAX_PLUGIN' . '/core/js/ajax-load-more.js');
```

However, not only it has no effect on the actual URL for the admin-ajax.php (that still refers to the siteurl, rather than the current home_url), but has changed the script location:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http:\/\/siteurl\/test\AJAX_PLUGIN/core/js/ajax-load-more.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
```

The siteurl is reversed proxy in Apache, can you please tell me whether what I am trying to achieve is even possible? How can have admin-ajax.php loaded on the front end? Can I move it to my theme folder? Do I have to modify the 3rd party plugin for that to work?

Thank you!

**EDIT2:**

By inspecting through the web developer tools I can see this error in the console:

```
http://siteurl/test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=alm_query…anonical_url=http://homeurl/test/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

What does it actually mean? What is alm_query…anonical_url?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If you dont mind please share URL where you are getting the console error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `wp-admin` in the path to the `admin-ajax.php` file. You can simply use `array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`.

```
$localiser = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php' ),
  );
```