# wordpress admin ajax url rename

Tags: ajax, url-rewriting

I came across this topic : [How can I rename the WordPress AJAX URL?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333617/how-can-i-rename-the-wordpress-ajax-url) on trying to rename the url for the admin ajax.php file. I tried the code suggested by Krzysiek Dróżdż which is this

```
// This will change the url for admin-ajax.php to /ajax/
function modify_adminy_url_for_ajax( $url, $path, $blog_id ) {
    if ( 'admin-ajax.php' == $path ) {
        $url = site_url('/ajax/');
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'admin_url', 'modify_adminy_url_for_ajax', 10, 3 );
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/?ajax/?$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

But I am getting post 404's under the renamed /ajax/ url and was wondering what I could be doing wrong and if this code would still work on newer versions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: https://github.com/devgeniem/wp-no-admin-ajax

> "A WordPress plugin that changes the WP AJAX routine and rewrites the
> ajax requests to custom url rather than admin-ajax.php back-end."